# document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] not working

Tags: javascript

I'm making site in which I have to add some element but only when they contain class .addEvent but when I try `document.getElementsByClassName(json[i].date)[0].classList.contains("addEvent")`
It shows me this error in console (json[i].date is something like: 2019-11-06):
`TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).classList is undefined`
And when I display date in console it shows as it should be.

Here is my whole javascript code, maybe it would help:

```
$(() => {
    var event;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getEvents.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function(json) {

            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                console.log(document.getElementsByClassName(json[i].date)[0].classList.contains("addEvent"));

                if (document.getElementsByClassName(json[i].date)[0].classList.contains("addEvent")) {
                    document.getElementsByClassName(json[i].date)[0].innerHTML += " <br/><span class='event'>" + json[i].name + "<br/>" + json[i].place + "</span>";
                    document.getElementsByClassName(json[i].date)[0].style.backgroundColor = json[i].color;
                    document.getElementsByClassName(json[i].date)[0].style.color = "#ffffff";
                    document.getElementsByClassName(json[i].date)[0].style.fontWeight = "bold";
                    document.getElementsByClassName(json[i].date)[0].style.opacity = "0.6";
                }
            }
        },

        error: function(error) {
            alert("error");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    var day;
    var shown = false;

    $("td.addEvent").click(function() {
        if (shown == false) {
            $(".addEventMenu").css("display", "block");
            day = getDay($(this));
            var clickedDay = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
            clickedDay[1].innerHTML += day;
            shown = true;
        }
    });

    function getDay(input) {
        return input.clone().children().remove().end().text();
    }

    $("button.addEventBtn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var year;
        var month = $(".month").val();
        const regex = /[0-9]{4}/gm;
        let m;

        while ((m = regex.exec($(".date").text())) !== null) {
            // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
            if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                regex.lastIndex++;
            }

            // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
            m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
                year = `${match}`;
            });
        }

        var name = $(".eventName").val();
        var description = $(".eventDescription").val();
        var place = $(".eventPlace").val();
        var startHour = $('.eventStartHour').val();
        var endHour = $('.eventEndHour').val();
        var color = $('.eventColor').val();
        var userId = $('input.userId').val();
        if (day < 10) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        var date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'addEvent.php',
            data: {
                'eventName': name,
                'eventDescription': description,
                'eventPlace': place,
                'eventStartHour': startHour,
                'eventEndHour': endHour,
                'eventColor': color,
                'eventDate': date,
                'userId': userId
            },
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data) {

            },
            error: function(request, status, error) {
                alert(request, status);
            }
        });
    });

    $("p.closeEventMenu").click(function() {
        $(".addEventMenu").css("display", "none");
        var clickedDateDay = $("p.clickedDay").text();
        clickedDateDay = clickedDateDay.replace(/\s+$/, '');
        $("p.clickedDay").text(clickedDateDay.substring(0, clickedDateDay.length - 2));
        shown = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: No, that code does not produce this error.

Comment: The [currently pending edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24598309) says _“hopefully it will trigger answers”_; a _[mre]_ would do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not confirming that the element exists before trying to use it.

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName(json[i].date)[0].classList.contains("addEvent"))
```

If no elements matching class json[i].date exist, this if will throw the exception.

You should confirm the selector is returning elements before trying to use any of them:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(json[i].date);
if(elements.length > 0 && elements[0].classList.contains("addEvent"))
```

This will confirm the element actually exists before attempting to gather any information (classList) from the element. Of course, whether or not the element exists depends on many other factors - but in this case it seems that there are not any elements matching the selector on the page.